# Using a larger drive in a RAID 1 setup

Tags: raid, raid1

Is it possible to introduce in a RAID 1 setup a larger drive using its free space for further uses?

**E.g:**

What we have:

```
sda - 250 GB HD
 |-- sda1 - /boot
 |-- sda2 - /

sdb - 500 GB HD
 |-- sdb1 - /boot
 |-- sdb2 - /
 |-- sdb3 - whatever

md - RAID1 setup
 |-- md0 - /boot - sd[ab]1
 |-- md1 - / - sd[ab]2
```

In this case we could use `sdb3` for something else. Is this possible? I've never set up a software RAID and this struck my mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `sdb3` is available for you to use as you wish.

In your example the MD devices would probably be `md0` and `md1` rather than `md0p1` and `md0p2`.